# Python- Append the find to add in the average

Tags: python-3.x, average

I am trying to generate 50lines of random integers between -20 and 20. Write these numbers to a file called random_numbers.txt and append the file to add in the average of these 50 numbers. I was able to generate 50 numbers but I can't find the average. It should be 0.28. Thank you for your help!
This is what I have so far:

```
import random
fileh= open("random_numbers.txt", "w")
for num in range(50):
  num= str(random.randint(-20,20))
  fileh.write(num+str("\n"))
fileh.close()

fileh= open("random_numbers.txt", "a")
s = fileh.readlines()
total=0
for line in s:
  num1=0
  num1+= float(line)
  total += num1
  average = total / 50
fileh.write("Average is:", average)
fileh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you calculate the average.

```
for line in s:
  num1=0
  num1+= float(line)
  total += num1
  average = total / 50    #this is inside a loop so you are writting it every time
fileh.write("Average is:", average)
fileh.close()
```

If you calculate the average inside the loop it will be modify everytime and then you will use the last calculated number.

Identation is very important in python.

try this:

```
for line in s:
  num1=0
  num1+= float(line)
  total += num1
average = total / 50 # No tab means it is outside the loop
fileh.write("Average is:", average)
fileh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute `total` while you are writing out the random numbers. Don't try to read them in again from the file you are appending to.